# Extending existing Record type

Tags: purescript

If I have a record type:

```
type Rec_ab = { a :: String, b :: Int }
```

Can I get **from it** type which is effectfully extended with `{c :: Boolean}` : `{ a :: String, b :: Int, c :: Boolean }`?

If I had a row, I could do it:

```
Row_ab = ( a :: String, b :: Int )

Rec_abc = { c :: Boolean | Row_ab }
```

but if I have a record `Rec_ab` how this should be solved? I'm not aware of the way of going from Record -> Row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can't.

If you need that kind of extensibility, your approach with `Row_ab` is good enough, but another possible solution is to parametrize the record and then use the parameter to extend it:

```
type Rec_ab r = { a :: String, b :: Int | r }
type Rec_abc = Rec_ab ( c :: Boolean )
```

This also allows you to write functions that would work with both `Rec_ab` and `Rec_abc`:

```
add42 :: forall r. Rec_ab r -> Rec_ab r
add42 r = r { b = r.b + 42 }
```

Comment: Is there a rationale behind an inability to extend existing records type? What is the problem of getting Record -> Row for example?

Comment: Same problem as getting `Maybe Int` -> `Int` for example. Remember that `{ a :: String }` is syntactic sugar for `Record ( a :: String )`

Comment: A side note to this answer: if we leave separate definition of the base Row we also use a nice type level operator `+` from Type.Row: try.purescript.org/?gist=f0d6efda76ecb09d85e847641b4480e8